# hGetContents being too lazy

Tags: haskell, file-io

I have the following snippet of code, which I pass to `withFile`:

```
text <- hGetContents hand 
let code = parseCode text
return code
```

Here hand is a valid file handle, opened with `ReadMode` and `parseCode` is my own function that reads the input and returns a Maybe.  As it is, the function fails and returns Nothing. If, instead I write:

```
text <- hGetContents hand 
putStrLn text
let code = parseCode text
return code
```

I get a Just, as I should.

If I do `openFile` and `hClose` myself, I have the same problem. Why is this happening? How can I cleanly solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code where you use `hClose` yourself? It sounds like you're closing it before the input has been required.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`hGetContents` isn't too lazy, it just needs to be composed with other things appropriately to get the desired effect. Maybe the situation would be clearer if it were were renamed `exposeContentsToEvaluationAsNeededForTheRestOfTheAction` or just `listen`.

`withFile` opens the file, does something (or nothing, as you please -- exactly what you require of it in any case), and closes the file.

It will hardly suffice to bring out all the mysteries of 'lazy IO', but consider now this difference in bracketing

```
 good file operation = withFile file ReadMode (hGetContents >=> operation >=> print)
 bad file operation = (withFile file ReadMode hGetContents) >>= operation >>= print

-- *Main> good "lazyio.hs" (return . length)
-- 503
-- *Main> bad "lazyio.hs" (return . length)
-- 0
```

Crudely put, `bad` opens and closes the file before it does anything; `good` does everything in between opening and closing the file. Your first action was akin to `bad`. `withFile` should govern all of the action you want done that that depends on the handle.

You don't need a strictness enforcer if you are working with `String`, small files, etc., just an idea how the composition works.  Again, in `bad` all I 'do' before closing the file is `exposeContentsToEvaluationAsNeededForTheRestOfTheAction`. In `good` I compose `exposeContentsToEvaluationAsNeededForTheRestOfTheAction` with the rest of the action I have in mind, then close the file.

The familiar `length` + `seq` trick mentioned by Patrick, or `length` + `evaluate` is worth knowing; your second action with `putStrLn txt` was a variant. But reorganization is better, unless lazy IO is wrong for your case.

```
$ time ./bad
bad: Prelude.last: empty list  
                        -- no, lots of Chars there
real    0m0.087s

$ time ./good
'\n'                -- right
()
real    0m15.977s

$ time ./seqing 
Killed               -- hopeless, attempting to represent the file contents
    real    1m54.065s    -- in memory as a linked list, before finding out the last char
```

It goes without saying that ByteString and Text are worth knowing about, but reorganization with evaluation in mind is better, since even with them the Lazy variants are often what you need, and they then involve grasping the same distinctions between forms of composition.  If you are dealing with one of the (immense) class of cases where this sort of IO is inappropriate, take a look at `enumerator`, `conduit` and co., all wonderful.

Comment: Using `evaluate` on the read `String` is pointless, as `evaluate` only evaluates to WHNF, i.e. the first `(:)` constructor. However, it might be appropriate to use it on the result of e.g. parsing the file, if that depends on the entire contents of the file.

Comment: Yes, this is stated in the documentation; I mentioned it because it is mentioned elsewhere here.

Comment: These `length` hacks are really revolting.

Comment: Doesn't this mean for most programs that you're worse off than just using `openFile "filename" ReadMose >=> hGetContents` and then never hClosing the handle? Because using withFile you have to complete the whole program's IO inside the callback or else you might expose yourself to a late read - except the handle is guaranteed to be closed at the latest conceivable point rather than at any point where you'd like to force it and report an error if there can be a subsequent late read?

Answer (score 9):

`hGetContents` uses lazy IO; it only reads from the file as you force more of the string, and it only closes the file handle when you evaluate the entire string it returns. The problem is that you're enclosing it in `withFile`; instead, just use `openFile` and `hGetContents` directly (or, more simply, `readFile`). The file will still get closed once you fully evaluate the string. Something like this should do the trick, to ensure that the file is fully read and closed immediately by forcing the entire string beforehand:

```
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

readCode :: FilePath -> IO Code
readCode fileName = do
    text <- readFile fileName
    evaluate (length text)
    return (parseCode text)
```

Unintuitive situations like this are one of the reasons people tend to avoid lazy IO these days, but unfortunately you can't change the definition of `hGetContents`. A strict IO version of `hGetContents` is available in the [strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict) package, but it's probably not worth depending on the package just for that one function.

If you want to avoid the overhead that comes from traversing the string twice here, then you should probably look into using a more efficient type than `String`, anyway; the `Text` type has [strict IO equivalents](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text-IO.html) for much of the `String`-based IO functionality, [as does `ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#g:26) (if you're dealing with binary data, rather than Unicode text).

Comment: I would say it *is* worth depending on `strict` just for strict `hGetContents`; that's exactly what the package is for! Don't propagate NIH-syndrome.

Comment: The definition of `hGetContents` in `System.IO.Strict` is the familiar `hGetContents h  = IO.hGetContents h >>= \s -> length s \`seq\` return s`; it's the oldest trick in the book, not a novel idea from `strict-0.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can force the contents of `text` to be evaluated using

```
length text `seq` return code
```

as the last line.

Comment: That only requires the number of elements to be evaluated, since length doesn't ever evaluate an element it is easily possible for a haskell implementation to only get as far as statting the file and with that implementation you'll still get an IO error when you try to use the data. `(let lseq = liftA2 seq in (length . filter (== '\0')) \`lseq\` return)` would be closer to complete, but there are still possible lazy sources of String which will have encodings for the last byte where (== '\0') doesn't require reading all of the bytes encoding the last character.