# Haskell: why does this code fail?

Tags: haskell, file-io, monads, lazy-evaluation

When I try to run this code...

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as LTIO
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT
import System.IO (IOMode(..), withFile)

getFirstLine :: FilePath -> IO String
getFirstLine path =
        withFile path ReadMode (\f -> do
                contents <- LTIO.hGetContents f
                return ("-- "++(LT.unpack . head $ LT.lines contents)++" --"))

main::IO()
main = do
        firstLine <- getFirstLine "/tmp/foo.csv"
        print firstLine
```

I get

```
"-- *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

... where I would expect it to print the first line of "/tmp/foo.csv".  Could you please explain why?  Ultimately, I'm trying to figure out how to create a lazy list of Texts from file input.

Comment: Does /tmp/foo.csv have anything in it?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because by the time the thunk that reads the content is evaluated the file has been closed.

Comment: Yes, the file does have some content in it.  Why would the file be closed when the thunk reads the content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hGetContents being too lazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485740/hgetcontents-being-too-lazy)

Comment: also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406463/withfile-vs-openfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Daniel Lyons mentions in a comment, this is due to IO and laziness interacting.

Imagine, if you will:

- `withFile` opens the file, to file handle `f`.
- Thunk using contents of `f` is returned.
- `withFile` closes the file.
- Thunk is evaluated.  There are no contents in a closed file.

This trap is mentioned on the [HaskellWiki / Maintaining laziness](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maintaining_laziness) page.

To fix, you can either read the whole file contents within `withFile` (possibly by forcing it with `seq`) or lazily close the file instead of using `withFile`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's like this: `withFile` closes the file after executing the function. `hGetContents` reads the contents lazily (lazy IO), and by the time it needs to read the stuff, the file is closed.

Instead of using `withFile`, try just using `openFile`, and not closing it. `hGetContents` will place the file in semi-closed state after it's reading from it. Or better, just read the contents directly using `readFile`